# GWT: The test class 'com.myco.clearing.commons.xml.XMLNodeTest' was not found in module

Tags: gwt, maven, junit, gwttestcase

I have a Maven (3.0.3) / GWT (2.4) project.  I'm trying to write some JUnit test cases but running into issues.  All my test cases extend GWTTestCase and include this code ...

```
@Override
public String getModuleName() {
    return "com.myco.clearing.product.ProductPlus";
}
```

The "ProductPlus.gwt.xml" file is located in my src/main/java directory.  To include that in my classpath I have this configured for my surefire-plugin ...

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
                <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>gwt.args</name>
                        <value>-out \${webAppDirectory}</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However, upon running "mvn clean test", I get all these errors, including this one ...

```
testParsingNodeWithAttributes(com.myco.clearing.commons.xml.XMLNodeTest)  Time elapsed: 2.563 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitFatalLaunchException: The test class 'com.myco.clearing.commons.xml.XMLNodeTest' was not found in module 'com.myco.clearing.product.ProductPlus'; no compilation unit for that type was seen
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.checkTestClassInCurrentModule(JUnitShell.java:743)
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1346)
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1309)
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:653)
at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:441)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:296)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1017)
```

This is a bizarre error because the class in question is in my src/test/java directory, which I have included as an "additionalClassPathElement" (above).  What other configurations do I need to make to correct this error? - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package for your test must be in the client classpath for the module specified. Based on the module's name, your test probably belongs in the `com.myco.clearing.product.client` package, or a subpackage of that.

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly that is achieved? Thanks.

Comment: How what is achieved, @Cornelius? The package is the same as the normal client code in the project, just in the test sources instead of the regular sources.